# Menu dropping into two rows due to loading of fonts

Tags: jquery, html, css

**QUESTIONS**

**Q1.**

I've asked a couple of the designers, they say that the menu dropping into two when loading is caused by the loading of fonts. I have seen sites that does this perfectly fine, so is there any way to keep the menu into one bar when loading as far as possible? I am using Google's ABEL font.

**Q2.**

Is it possible to allow certain images to load first, as I have smaller images on my site that are positioned on top of the images and it looks kind of messy.

**Q3.**

With that being said, some tell me to simply ignore them. Some suggested to do another way, which is to make it load before showing the site's fully-loaded content. Is there any way to do this (I don't want any loading bar or whatsoever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWERS**

**A1.**

Some fonts might cause the menu to spill over onto second line. You can take care of this by setting a fixed width with some buffer on either sides. If that is not feasible, try reducing the letter-spacing of the button label as `letter-spacing: 0.5px;`.

**A2.**

Yes its absolutely possible to load certain images first. To achieve this, you can check out the [lazy loading plugin of jquery](http://plugins.jquery.com/lazyload/)

**A3.**

Few things you can do to load images quickly:
1. get smaller, optimized images from your designer for thumbnails
2. if the background image is huge, consider using [pattern fill (using background repeat)](http://subtlepatterns.com/)